# "Todo list" or "to-do list"

Tags: word-choice, orthography

I always thought it was a *todo* list, and quite a few places online refer to it as *todo*, but various spell checkers are telling me it should be *to-do*.

The only meaning I could find was [a reference by dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to-do) which is different from the use I need for the word.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Wiktionary defines both [to-do](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to-do#Noun) and [todo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/todo#Noun):

> **Noun**
> to-do (*plural* to-dos)
> ...
> 2. A task that has been noted as one that must be completed, especially on a list.
> *My **to-do** list has been growing longer every day.*

And:

> **Noun**
> todo (*plural* todos)
> (*US*) A task yet to be done; an item on a to-do list.

You can use whichever you want, but be consistent. *To-do* is a little clearer, but hyphens are naturally lost as languages evolve (to-day, wire-less), so *todo* should be fine too.

---

**Edit:** Waggers makes a very good point that *todo* isn't yet as widely adopted as to-do. So you may be better off sticking to to-do.

[Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20do%20list,todo%20list&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of "todo list" vs "to do list" (+ "list" because to avoid the fuss and commotion meanings, and "to do" will include "to-do"):

[image: to do list vs todo list]

Comparison of term on newspaper websites, but note "to-do list" also returns hits for "to do list":

| Phrase | guardian.co.uk | bbc.co.uk | nytimes.com | cnn.com |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *todo list* | 16 | 3,370 | 27 | 174 |
| *to-do list* | 2,350 | 79,000 | 130,000 | 30,100 |

Comment: A search for *to-do* also has zero results, so I don't think Google Ngram Viewer works for "to-do list". In fact, books containing "to-do list" are returned under an Ngram search for "to do list".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Well spotted! I'd read the results the wrong way around as well. ["To do list"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+do+list%2Ctodo+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) seems to match for "to-do list".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Search Ngrams for "to - do list" (put spaces around the hyphen) and [it'll work](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+do+list%2Ctodo+list%2Cto+-+do+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  *To-do* seems the most popular by far.

Comment: @drɱ65δ: Interesting… So both "to do list" and "to - do list" match "to-do list", but "to-do list" doesn't? How are we to make sense of Ngram results? :-)

Comment: The usage of "todo" seems to have originated in software engineering. These are engineers, not english majors and many of them speak english as a second language. It is likely that this version gained popularity starting as a wrong use of "to-do" much like "game over" is now standard for what should've been "the game is over."

Answer (score 9):

The OED has *to do* and *to-do*, but not *todo*. *Todo* looks like an extinct bird to me.

Comment: What years do they have in the OED for the task meaning?

Comment: The earliest citation for a to-do list is dated 1921, from a US source.

Answer (score 3):

While "todo" is found in some dictionaries (such as Wiktionary) it is less common in more established dictionaries such as the [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinslanguage.com/results.aspx), and the [entry in the Chambers 21st Century Dictionary only lists the hyphenated form](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=todo&title=21st). While Hugo is correct that often the language evolves and hyphens are eventually dropped, this process takes time and at present *todo* is **not** widely recognised as a single word in the way that "today" and "wireless" are. Indeed, this Google Books N-gram illustrates this very clearly:

[image: Google Books Ngram of "todo list" versus "to-do list"]

I would therefore advise *against* using "todo" and side with the spell-checkers.

Comment: How do you know those `to-do`s in the Ngram are listed tasks and not a fuss or commotion? But this other [Ngram of "todo list" vs. "to-do list"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=todo+list%2Cto-do+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows you're right, to-do is still by far the most common. And some searches over some newspaper websites confirm this.

Comment: See ShreevatsaR's comment on my answer: we read the Ngram results the wrong way round, and "to-do list" doesn't return any results. Use "to do list" instead.

Answer (score 2):

**TODO** (often in all-caps like that) is often used by programmers as a comment in their code (or in their presentations) to denote that something still needs to be done.

From [Jalayn's answer on the software engineering SE site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/125324/304087):

> Modern IDEs recognize the `TODO` comments and they are as such visible in their own panel/window/tab, so they are theoretically not lost (I'm thinking Eclipse and Visual Studio, both I know enough to remember that they recognize it).

Answer (score 2):

"Todo" in Spanish means "everything", so I prefer "to-do" not to confuse myself ;o)

Answer (score -1):

In short, both are correct. Though in the purest sense, it could be that neither are.

Most dictionaries seem to contain only the classical definition ("a disturbance or fuss") rather than the modern one that most people use today ("something to be completed"). I was unable to find any "task" definition other than in Wiktionary and The Free Dictionary; at least online, it's missing from the New Oxford American Dictionary, Collins English Dictionary, Chambers 21st Century Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, Cambridge Online Dictionary, and Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English. Can anyone confirm this?

According to the Online Etymology Dictionary, *To-do* came into use in the 1570's, meaning "proper or necessary to be done". A newer meaning emerged in the 1820's, being "a disturbance or fuss". I saw someone quote a 1920's figure for a resurgence of the "task" meaning, but according to the N-Grams it looks like that didn't happen until at least the 80's.

The few dictionaries that recognize the "task" meaning generally consider both *to-do* and *todo* as proper. Though as others have noted here, *to-do* is vastly preferred by formal publications; only in the programming world and some informal contexts does *todo* seem to be more common.

Comment: In to-do/todo list, the term is an adjective. All that you have to say about the noun "todo" is irrelevant here, and just muddies the water.

Comment: @Drew I apologize if I added to the confusion. Though to be fair, I haven't found *any* relevant dictionary entries for a noun, adjective, verb, whatever. Which at least supports my argument that it's not a word recognized by a proper language authority, and is a slang term left up to personal interpretation as dictated by popular use (hence everyone's mad dash to use n-gram searches).