# Is a "To Do List" familiar to other countries?

Tags: translation

I'm researching if a "to do list" is a familiar term or concept to English speakers around the world.

I found this related question on how to [**spell** *to do*.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46217/todo-list-or-to-do-list) Specifically, [Hugo's answer hints that *to-do list* may be familiar at least to the US and UK](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/46220/24846).

My specific scenario is explaining the idea of a "task" (for example, what Microsoft calls a task in their Outlook program). Would a *to do list* be an okay comparison for English speakers of various countries (the US, UK, Netherlands, and Japan could be the primary audiences)?

Comment: I've never thought of the Netherlands or Japan as an English-speaking country, especially the latter.

Comment: I agree they're not English-speaking countries. The explanations will likely be given *in English* to audiences that understand English, possibly as a second language.

Comment: @tchrist in Japan, there's English, Jim, but not as we know it. (Note for pedants: yes, I'm snowcloning a "Beam me up Scotty").

Answer (score 1):

As far as the U.S., I think it's safe to say that it's almost a universally understood phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine for the UK.

I'd definitely hyphenate it, though: "to-do list".

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry. I am not a native speaker, but the first time I saw this expression I immediately understood what it meant and adopted it. This sort of construction is one of the beauties of the English language when compared with more cumbersome languages. (*Liste des choses à faire* is word for word *list of things to do* and the correct translation of *to-do list* into French.)

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a sense the phrase is easy to understand. Animadversor has a point that it may not be a good fit for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that one should equate a to-do list with a list of tasks; consider this list:

1. Mow lawn.
2. Pick up dry cleaning.
3. See movie.
4. Go bar-hopping

There are four things to be done (or four to-do's, if you like), but only two tasks.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should just use *real world tasks* to explain *tasks* in software. :-) In my case, these tasks include subject, action or description, assigned user (owner), location, and due date. Examples from tasks in projects might be a better fit.

Comment: That said, I think that Outlook doesn't make the distinction. I'm pretty sure that plenty of users have what are in fact non-task to-dos listed as tasks, or should I say _Tasks_, in Outlook, and that they do so untroubled by any of this.